# Correct MSBuild target to inject my own task for code generation

Tags: .net-6.0, msbuild-task

I am trying to implement something like custom WPF with xaml compilation and partial classes code generation.
I am doing that currently on `AfterTargets="AfterCompile"` target, because I need my main assembly to be compiled to have possibility to use its type via reflection in my task. But I faced with the issue that on that step assembly is not fully available and `DefinedTypes` property throws exception.

Does anyone know correct MSBuild target for that kind of manipulations?
I would appreciate for your help.

Comment: Ideally you'd rely on a Roslyn Source Generator. That way you can generate the source prior to the 1st compilation step. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview

Comment: @jessehouwing So, using SourceGenerator I can replace MSBuild tasks in this case? Is it possible to fail compilation using generator in case if xaml will be incorrect, for example? Or do I have possibility to access to the referenced assemblies of my main project to get types that I need?

Comment: You'll have access to the interpreted sources similar to reflection. More info https://github.com/amis92/csharp-source-generators

Comment: @jessehouwing I tried this feature and seems that it is still very unstable. Could not manage it to work properly after the whole day of attempts. So, I go back to my first question - which MSBuild task is the most appropriate for my needs described in the question?

Comment: There really isn't one. The dual pass compile for XAML is a very complex system consisting of multiple targets that interweave into the standard compilation pipeline greatly slowing down compilation and having caused many bugs.if you want to replicate that behavior, my recommendation would be to look into the XAML compilation target files. But there isn't just 1 thing to override.